# buildfarm: error while trying to run reconfigure script for master

Tags: ros, buildfarm, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to setup a build farm to build our software solution. However I have an error when I run

> ./reconfigure.bash master

Here's the output:

```
2018-02-06 10:46:56 +0100 Puppet (err): Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Error from DataBinding 'hiera' while looking up 'ntp::autoupdate': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 34 column 1 at /root/buildfarm_deployment/modules/profile/manifests/ros/base.pp:8:3 on node ubuildfarm.
```

Does anyone have a clue about whats is going wrong and how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281885/buildfarm:-error-while-trying-to-run-reconfigure-script-for-master/) by [tolliug](https://answers.ros.org/users/33344/tolliug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:
Something to check: no errors in your `buildfarm_deployment_config` yaml files? It's all valid yaml?

**Comment by [tolliug](https://answers.ros.org/users/33344/tolliug/) on 2018-02-06**:
Sure something must be wrong but the error targets ntp services, so should I focused on timezone? I tried with America/Los_Angeles and Europe/Paris without any effect. So I don't know how to solve that and where to search for help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:\

> the error targets ntp services,

as with all parsers, I would say that the ntp class is just the first that happens to come across an error, and the parser prints that as an error. It doesn't mean the error is necessarily there.

> so should I focused on timezone?

No, I don't believe so.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:
You could use something like [adrienverge/yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) to verify your yaml off-line.

But as I wrote, it's just a first thing to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It definitely seems like something was unexpected in the hiera (yaml format) config data.

From the error message:

```
could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 34 column 1
```

would indicate a possible location, but it doesn't give a filename and it's possible that the position information refers to an intermediate converged file which is the result of merging the master and common hiera configurations. But I'd look at your configuration files.

To check YAML files, parsing them with the yamllint tool mentioned by @gvdhoorn works.

You can also use a language with an interactive interpreter to do a quick check. Ruby supports yaml parsing in the standard library. So checking looks a little like

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require "yaml"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> YAML.load_file "hiera/hieradata/common.yaml"
=> {"jenkins::slave::ui_user"=>"admin", "jenkins::slave::ui_pass"=>"changeme", "jenkins::slave::masterurl"=>"http://master:8080", "master::ip"=>"172.30.1.145", "repo::ip"=>"172.30.1.69", "ssh_keys"=>{"ssh key comment / title"=>{"key"=>"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCXukygCeYbRCHP7IRxCIJpVTKYVtqIXRubANWVjGAQYEM+4FHca0ZCx/k+xOERj49ZIySXMOKdFlWELezYCnpJl6Q1qE2zPR4eSU/nEo9BwaCqbIrKoToND0L65goi4Ya/mKn3NBNkYJbAl+hHW0QQKhgyme5b1JgWZjkKX7b5eqzlkn0ic7hNUmRuj3gjJAvfvvMaVE0VIxnXSuw+SoxE8Q33qno4vtkxo8/6i1MpQgxB26e7UdeVY8xuUukByD0+pUARBMFlpOCu8ycMYcoMdJKiqVSRvn3/kg5lj39qro8kMwqR/m2nrTtZMiEfCNYSEuYNLjLUvRQbBGg8dxgp", "type"=>"ssh-rsa", "user"=>"root"}}, "autoreconfigure"=>false, "autoreconfigure::command"=>"bash -c \"cd /root/buildfarm_deployment_config && git fetch origin standalone-host && git reset --hard origin/standalone-host && ./reconfigure.bash\""}
```

With `pyyaml` installed you can do something similar with ipython.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-07**:
@nuclearsandwich: this is not github, indent blocks with 4 spaces for verbatim formatting. Three backticks don't work.